# git rebasing a very old branch

Tags: git, rebase

My project uses a branch (say FEATURE) which was branched off master sine a long time (about 1 year).

On this branch there has been 100's of commits .... same thing on master as well.
The 2 path have diverged quite a lot, and I would like to rebase the FEATURE branch on master, to reduce the differences.
The rebase itself was lengthy, but can be solved. I did the rebase in a separate branch. Once the branch will be building correctly and thoroughly tested, my goal is to overwrite the FEATURE branch with it.
This is a bit scary ....

Shall I simply do a `git push --force --set-upstream origin/FEATURE` ?

Thanks,
Jacques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to push your rebased `FEATURE` branch to the remote, then use:

```
git push --force origin FEATURE
```

If you instead want to overwrite the `FEATURE` branch with some other rebased branch, called `FEATURE_OTHER`, then use:

```
git checkout FEATURE
git reset --hard FEATURE_OTHER
git push --force origin FEATURE
```

Comment: Actually, I realise that maybe i had it wrong: I created a branch from FEATURE top (FEATURE_REBASED) and i rebased this branch. But my intention is somehow to replace "FEATURE" with it ? Is my strategy correct ? Shall I do in that case git push --force --set-upstream origin/FEATURE ?

Comment: I am now very confused (perhaps even more than you) about what you actually did here.  If you want to "replace" `FEATURE` with some other rebased version branch, then just use my second option and hard reset `FEATURE` to some other branch.

Comment: hmmm .. you edited your answer didn't you ? I guess that answers pretty much to what i wanted to do (really, replacing FEATURE branch with FEATURE_REBASED). I try to be extra cautious here, as there is no way backward ... and a lot of code depends on that